# AlertDialog.Builder setItems list with another

Tags: android, dialog, alert, builder

I'm trying to have a list of items that when touched will open another list of items. Rather like a sub menu of items. This is because my first list is getting to long and I would like to group some together into a sub menu.

```
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, final int position, long id) {

           final CharSequence[] items = {"Gallery Image Menu", "View pattern", "Delete pattern", "Locate pattern in list view", "Row Counter (with pattern)", "Share Pattern", "Share Image", "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(grid.this);
            builder.setTitle(selectedimage);
            builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {


                    if (item == 0){
                        //first menu 1st item
                        dialog.dismiss();

                        final CharSequence[] items2 = {"Rotate image 180"+"\u00B0", "Rotate image 90"+"\u00B0", "Add image from pattern",  "Add image from file", "Add image from camera", "Remove image", "Cancel"};

                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(grid.this);
                        builder2.setTitle(selectedimage);
                        builder2.setItems(items2, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog2, int item) {


                                if(item == 0){
                                    //2nd menu, 1st item
                                    dialog2.dismiss();

                                    //do something
                                    return;
                                }

                                if(item == 1){
                                    dialog2.dismiss();
                                    //2nd menu, 2nd item
                                    //do something else
                                    return;
                                }


                            AlertDialog alert2 = builder2.create();
                            alert2.show();

                            }
                        });
                    }


                    if (item == 1){
                        //first menu 2nd item
                    }


                    if(item == 2){
                        //1st menu, 3rd item
                    }


                    if(item == 3){

                    }

                    //..... etc


                }
            });
            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();


        }

    });//gridView.setOnItemClickListener
```

The first builder displays as expected but when I select the first option which I want to open the 2nd builder the first builder closes and returns to activity.

When in debug mode the 2nd builder code is read as if it was going to display but then both close.

Perhaps you cannot do this?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misplaced the

```
AlertDialog alert2 = builder2.create();
alert2.show();
```

part. Move it 3 lines down, after `});`